# Exposing service WSDL in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-esb

Based on WSO2 Architecture blog posts

- http://wso2.com/blogs/architecture/2013/05/a-pragmatic-approach-to-the-api-faade-pattern/
- http://wso2.com/blogs/architecture/2013/05/implementing-an-api-faade-with-the-wso2-api-management-platform/

I tried to publish API, but exposed WSDL is direct link to back-end ESB.
I planned to expose to outer Internet just API Manager so all calls will be proxied through it. Access to ESB should be limited to internal services and not to public.

Did I something wrong in configuration or API Manager doesn't support this function?
I use WSO2 API Manager 1.4.0 and WSO2 ESB 4.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO NOT expose the WSDL of ESB proxy service. The use case for exposing wsdl to allow users to get to know the service contract. You can host the wsdl in a separate location and provide that in the APIManager.

But i think, when we host a WSDL from APIManager, it's port bindings need to be changed  according to the gateway node.SO,the requests will be routed via gateway..But that feature is not available in the released versions..We will consider that in the future release.